# How to deploy a svelte kit app after build using nginx as web server

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, svelte, sveltekit

I have a svelte kit project. I want to deploy the app in an Nginx web server after an `npm run build`. At the moment I have a node container and I use to start using `npm run preview`. It's working fine, but I want to deploy in a production environment using `build`.

How could I do that?

ref: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#command-line-interface-svelte-kit-build

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Caleb Irwin said, you can run `node ./build/index.js`

The NGINX configuration will look like this:

```
upstream sveltekit {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  keepalive 8;
}


server {
  # listen ... 
  # servername ...

  # root ... (folder with an index.html in case of sveltekit being crashed)

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://sveltekit;
    proxy_redirect off;

    error_page 502 = @static;
  }

  location @static {
    try_files $uri /index.html =502;
  }
}
```

(I'm not a NGINX pro and welcomes feedback to improve on it)

You may also want to make the SvelteKit app listen only to localhost by adding the environment `HOST=127.0.0.1` before running `node build/index.js`. This will prevent the port 3000 from being reached from the outside.

You can also look into using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) to manage the sveltekit process, including running it on each of your cores in cluster mode, automatic restart in case of server crash / reboot.

Comment: Thank you. I will learn more about pm2. I use a reverse haproxy up front, with ssl and other settings. I tried this settings in the containers, `node ./build/index.js`. In fact, I think now nginx is not needed to run. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing issues with the nginx configuration. It works for location /. But if I want to point the sveltekit app to a different location (e.g. /survey), it doesn't work. Why could that be?

Comment: @sridharraman try setting `config.kit.paths.base` your `svelte.config.js` to `/survey`.

Comment: @coyotte508, let me try it. I see an issue in my dev app itself now. If I go to localhost:3000, it asks me if I meant /survey. Going to localhost:3000/survey renders it fine, but some of my fetch commands fail as I need to hard-code the 'survey/' path everywhere. I wonder if there is a cleaner approach?

Comment: You can make a fetch wrapper to add a base path? `function bfetch(path, options) { return fetch(base+path, options)}` Maybe there is a better way, would need to look into the docs. You can `import {base} from "$app/paths"`.

Comment: @coyotte508, changing the base worked somewhat. The app is accessible at the /survey location. But none of the components/assets within _app get loaded. What could be the reason?

Comment: The @Duke answer support serving the static files as static files, cache on the images and pass only the real nodejs work to nodejs.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a static website (ie no endpoints) you should use `@sveltejs/adapter-static`. It will put the files you should serve in `/build` directory. You can then serve the generated pages using NGINX. A sample NGINX config would be:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.jasonrigden.com;
        root /path/to/build/directory;
        index index.html;
}
```

If your site is not static you should use `@sveltejs/adapter-node` and run that in your container. You could put NGINX in front of it to use its features (SSL, load balancing, firewall, etc). After building your site (using `npm run build`) you can run `node ./build/index.js`.

Alternatively, you could use Netlify, Vercel, or Cloudflare Pages to host you site.

To see how to change your adapter see the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#adapters).

Good luck!

Comment: My website isn't static, it's actually an enterprise app. I use a reverse haproxy up front, with ssl and other settings. I tried this settings in the containers, `node ./build/index.js`. It's working fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This config is for running SvelteKit with node-adapter.

```
upstream sveltekit-server {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  keepalive 8;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  root /home/deploy/frontend/build/client;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @sveltekit;
  }

  location @sveltekit {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;

    proxy_pass http://sveltekit-server;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # error_page 502 = @static;
  }

  location ^~ /_app/immutable/ {
    # gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
  }
}
```

Here's a gist --

https://gist.github.com/dukejones/01fd7ddbfc8cdac4e02c6105d26ca7fe

The best thing about nginx is it can just serve the static files with strong caching for immutable files with content-hashed naming, and pass the rest onto the nodejs server.

Of course use some process manager (systemd etc) to keep the nodejs server running, or run nodejs in docker & expose the port.

Comment: on /_app/immutable/ location I think there is no need to have the @sveltekit upstream

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to deploy a Svelte Kit app to my Google Cloud Engine virtual machine and serve it using Nginx.  I've still got some outstanding questions myself, but so far these are my steps:

1. Run the build locally as per the docs referenced by OP. Local directory: `$ npm run build`
2. Local directory:$ `gcloud compute scp --recurse build/ user@gcpinstance:~/Desktop`
3. Local directory:$ `gcloud compute scp package*.* user@gcpinstance:~/Desktop`
4. On the remote vm, from the directory to which I uploaded my build folder and the package files, (e.g.~/Desktop$), I run `npm install`.  That re-created the node-modules folder (otherwise it takes forever to upload the node-modules folder from the local machine).
5. ~/Desktop$ `mkdir SvelteKitProd/`
6. ~/Desktop$ `mv package*.* build/ node-modules/ SvelteKitProd/`
7. ~/Desktop$ `sudo chown -R root:root SvelteKitProd/`
8. ~/Desktop$ `mv SvelteKitProd/ /var/www/domainname/`
   9   ~/Desktop$ `cd /var/www/domainname/`
9. /var/www/domainname:$ `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/domainname` (this is my nginx configuration for this domain and this app).

```
upstream hijacked-media {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    server_name hijacked.media www.hijacked.media;
    #root /var/www/hijacked.media/sveltekittest/sveltekitprod/PROD-GCP;
    #       index index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/hijacked.media.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/hijacked.media.error.log;

    location  / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

        proxy_pass http://hijacked-media;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hijacked.media/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hijacked.media/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.hijacked.media) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = hijacked.media) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name hijacked.media www.hijacked.media;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

11. /var/www/domainname$ `pm2 start SvelteKitProd/build/index.js`

I'm still trying to figure out what all I need to do in order to serve multiple apps each from its own top-level domain.  I was hoping that I could change the PORT once built and uploaded (see the build/index.js file), but so far that isn't working for me.  So I'll try specifying a unique port number while building it locally or messing with it once uploaded to the remote server; or perhaps use PM2 and Nginx to make multiple apps work on the same port, e.g. 3000.